# Mac OSX: I have created a launchagent plist for Geth so it runs in the background on startup. Can I reattach it to terminal?

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx

I wanted to be able to run Geth in the background without having to think about it in order to assist the network. So I created a .plist and added it to /library/launchagents. Now when I start my computer, Geth starts up and runs in the background.

However there are times that I want to be able to interact with Geth and view the running script in Terminal. Is it possible to reattach Geth to Terminal?

If not, can anyone recommend a better way that I can run Geth in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a console, you can run `geth attach` to connect to a running geth instance, and it will give you the same effect as `geth console`. If you need the output from the main terminal (i.e. the various logs about blocks and whatnot) you might be able to redirect the output to a file and read said file, perhaps with `tail`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is the logs I am looking for. I want to check to see if Geth is behaving correctly when started from /library/Launchagents. On one occasion in particular it took up all my CPU and was downloading a hell of a lot of data, whereas it is usually clocking a maximum of 4-5% of CPU and downloading only a trickle of data. It was not caused by needing to catch up with the blockchain, because this happened after a restart. I'm not really comfortable with Terminal so I am struggling a bit.